# Not retrieving any products, In App Purchases

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

```
- (void) requestProductData
{
SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
initWithProductIdentifiers: [NSSet setWithObjects: @"com.mycompany.appname.item1", @"com.mycompany.appname.item2", nil]];
request.delegate = self;
[request start];
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:
    (SKProductsResponse *)response
{
NSArray *myProducts = response.products;
NSLog(@"%i Products retrieved", [myProducts count]);

[request autorelease];
}
```

As you can see, I set up a NSLog to return the number of products.
I keep getting 0 Products retrieved.
The Product Ids && bundle Identifier match with itunes connect.
In app purchase statuses are "Ready to Submit", app status is "Prepare for upload"
Is there something else I'm supposed to set up in itunes connect? or something with the code?

**EDIT:**
Does it make a difference that I do not currently have iOS Paid Apps contract in effect?

Answer (score 0):

The apple server isn't finding your products, you should see them in `response.invalidProductIdentifiers`.  Most likely, you haven't created them in iTunesConnect, or you may have a typo. If your products haven't been approved yet, you might have to ensure you're in the sandbox.

Comment: They are `response.invalideProductIdentifiers`
I've doubled checked all spelling.
how do i ensure sandbox?

Comment: If you use compile-and-run in xcode, it should be sandboxed aumatically.

Comment: Yea i thought so too, I am in sandbox by default.
So what's the problem?

Comment: I've created test user but that isn't needed until purchasing the product. I'm having trouble just retrieving the list..

Comment: Does it make a difference that I do not currently have iOS Paid Apps contract in effect?